# Policy on homework?

Tags: discussion

I've just replied to a question where the poster was honest enough to add a tag "home work". The question itself was not really the home work I guess (it was [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/not-sure-how-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-equations-in-maple13)), but more how to do something in Maple. Of course, one can say to read the manual...

So my question: how does the community respond to home work (either tagged as such by the OP or clearly visible from the question)?

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of whether you ultimately decide to allow homework questions or not, such background and contextual information should be included **in the body of the question itself.** You should *not* use a  [homework](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag to label them.

Tags are there to describe what the question is about. Labeling a question as "homework" is not what tagging is for. It is largely meta to the question. See:

[**The death of meta tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Thanks for putting this in a cross-site context.  I was aware that some of the StackExchange sites have deprecated/burninated the homework tag, but it was still turning over in my mind to what extent this generalizes to all SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the OP has demonstrated sufficient thought and effort, it's perfectly fine to post a homework style question.

Comment: Should we then maintain the tag "homework" and promote its use (by OPs and respondents)?